# How to display items in an array, within another array, onto HTML on meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, meteor, spacebars

This is my js code:

```
Template.listModules.helpers({
    'item' : function() {
        var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
        var stuff = Events.find(
        {
            createdBy: currentUser,
            startDate: { $gte: new Date() }
        }, {sort: {module:1, startDate:1}}).fetch();
        var displayArray = testing();
        return displayArray;
    },
});

function testing(){
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
     var array = Events.find(
        {
            createdBy: currentUser,
            startDate: { $gte: new Date() }
        }, {sort: {module:1, startDate:1}}).fetch();

     var finalArr = [];
     var currentArr = [];
     currentArr.push(array[0]);
     for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].module == array[i-1].module){
            currentArr.push(array[i])
        } else {
            finalArr.push(currentArr);
            currentArr=[];
            currentArr.push(array[i]);
        }
        if(i+1 == array.length){
            finalArr.push(currentArr);
        }
    };
    console.log(finalArr);
    return finalArr;
}
```

and this is my current HTML code:

```
<template name="listModules">
    <h2>List of Modules</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each item}}
        <li>{{module}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

![this is the current finalArr that i have] https://ibb.co/jAyWDo

how do i display for example, the module string on the front end, html side. I've read online that some people managed to do it by giving an id to the array and having it as {{#each id}} but i'm not too sure how to give an id to the array here.

My goal is to do 2 loops so i can separate the 3 arrays into 3 text boxes, and have their content shown in the separate boxes.

Answer (score 0):

finalArr must instead be a collection instead of an array (call it finalCollection). Initialize like:

> finalCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);

and then insert the contents like

> finalCollection.insert({arr:currentArr});

Note that each item will have an id!
Once all contents are in the collection return all contents by doing

> return finalCollection.find({});

Html must use this object to get the module

```html
<template name="listModules">
    <h2>List of Modules</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each item}}
        <li>{{this.module}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

This is an ugly way of doing it. Hope it helps.